# Test E2E Cypress Laravel Jetstream fail click

Tags: laravel, automated-tests, cypress, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I wrote the following test in cypress that registers but gives me problems in click management account:

```
import faker from 'faker'
describe('Registration', () => {
const email = faker.internet.email()
const password = faker.internet.password()
it('successfully registering', () => {
    cy.visit('http://l8.test/register')
    cy.get('input[name=name]').type(faker.name.findName())
    cy.get('input[name=email]').type(email)
    cy.get('input[name=password]').type(password)
    cy.get('input[name=password_confirmation]').type(password)
    cy.get('button').contains('Register').click()
    cy.url().should('contain', '/dashboard')
    //I would like to click on the Management Account, but I can't
    cy.get('button.flex.text-sm.border-2.border-transparent.rounded-full.focus:outline-none.focus:border-gray-300.transition.duration-150.ease-in-out').click()
    //   cy.contains('Logout').click()
})
})
```

give me following error:

button.flex.text-sm.border-2.border-transparent.rounded-full.focus:outline-none.focus:border-gray-300.transition.duration-150.ease-in-out
Error
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: outline-none

basically I would like him to click this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  cy.get('button.flex.text-sm.border-2.border-transparent.rounded-full').click()
```